# SPRING BATCH : How to configure remote chunking for multiple jobs running in a task executor

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-batch, horizontal-scaling

I am new to spring batch processing. I am using **remote chunking** where there is a master , multiple slaves and ActiveMQ for messaging.

Master has a job and a job launcher and the **job launcher has a task-executor** which is having following configuration
      **`<task:executor id="batchJobExecutor" pool-size="2"queue-capacity="100" />`**.
Chunk configuration is

```
<bean id="chunkWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="messagingOperations" ref="messagingGateway" />
    <property name="replyChannel" ref="replies" />
    <property name="throttleLimit" value="50" />
    <property name="maxWaitTimeouts" value="60000" />
</bean>

<bean id="chunkHandler"
    class="org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.RemoteChunkHandlerFactoryBean">
    <property name="chunkWriter" ref="chunkWriter" />
    <property name="step" ref="someJobId" />
</bean>

<integration:service-activator
    input-channel="requests" output-channel="replies" ref="chunkHandler" />
```

So we are allowed to run two jobs at a time and the remaining jobs will be in the queue.
When two jobs are submitted Master is creating the chunk and submitting to the queue and slave is processing.

But the acknowledgment from the slave to master is giving error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Message contained wrong job instance id [9331] should have been [9332].
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:385) ~[Assert.class:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter.getNextResult
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

The `ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter` is only designed for one concurrent step - you need to put it in step scope so each job gets its own instance - [see this test case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-integration/src/test/resources/org/springframework/batch/integration/chunk/RemoteChunkFaultTolerantStepIntegrationTests-context.xml#L44)

**EDIT**

Actually, no; that won't work - since the bean instances are using the same reply channel, they could get each other's replies. I opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2507).

Comment: Actually i tried putting step scope, but it is giving the same error, Is there any implementation of ChunkItemWriter which i can use for this case

Comment: Could this be achieved by using a queue that supports routing? For instance, using Kafka, your "producer" step could inject in the message (or its metadata) an identifier, which could be used as the routing key on the responses. Given that Kafka, routes based on that key, each step will get back only the responses to the messages it initiated. Do you think it would work?

Answer (score -1):

This is a very old post, but I think the issue you see here might be related to the throttle limit being larger than the `maxWaitTimouts` value `4`.

What we have seen is that the implementation will not read more than `maxWaitTimeouts` entries from the reply queue after the job finished. I think this is a bug.

See also the question I asked on stackoverflow here : [Remote batch job does not read all responses in afterStep method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47227650/remote-batch-job-does-not-read-all-responses-in-afterstep-method)

I made a bug report for this as well: https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2651 and am creating a PR to fix the issue.